# Why can I enter an invalid contract address in the Remix IDE and still work with it?

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-invocation

I successfully deployed a contract to a local Ethereum development network:

```
notarisation_1       | Address of deployed contract
notarisation_1       | ----------------------------
notarisation_1       | 0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1
notarisation_1       | { blockNumber: '0' }
notarisation_1       | {
notarisation_1       |   res: {
```

When I try to interact with it from within the Remix Ethereum IDE and enter its address in the "At Address" input field and click the corresponding button, it is shown ("loaded") at the bottom and I can interact with it.

However, when I try to change some parts of the address above (e.g. change the last number from 1 to 2) and then click on the button again, it is also shown at the bottom.

Why does it behave like this? I expect an error message instead when I try to access a contract at an address where none exists.

[image: Remix IDE screenshot]

Comment: Seems like a nice feature to have, you should report it to their github repo https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project.